# BQ Aquaris E5 HD - Ubuntu Touch -Double tap wake up

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have been using my BQ Aquaris E5 HD phone now for a few weeks now and I just wanted to know if there was any way to wake the phone up (from stand-by) by a double tap on the screen? Rather than having to press the power button on the side all the time.

A few days ago, I was with a friend looking at the phone and I double tapped on the black screen and it woke up. We were both surprised by that. I did this again the next day and the double taps did nothing.

Comment: I looked for the exact same thing, and apparently there isn't an option for that... Also for Android, some phones (Xperia Z2) apparently have hardware for that, and so provide an option for that in Settings - those phones that don't have this, use apps to "fake-blank" the screen, so it is still powered, and the touch sensor still reacts - but then it's not a real "sleep", so you still waste a lot of power. Btw, I also noticed on E5 if you set it to sleep, and then tap it in the next few seconds, it wakes (apparently, in that period the sensor is not yet put to sleep)...

Comment: Thanks for the update. It would appear that it may not be possible on the E5. I have noticed that if you tap on the screen (when black) after a notification has been received, the screen comes back on.

Comment: I also found this comparison page: https://versus.com/en/huawei-ascend-g7-vs-bq-aquaris-e5-hd-ubuntu-edition - and it lists "wake on double tap" for the huawei but not for the E5; so indeed, probably not possible ...

Comment: That is a shame, but it gives me a good reason to get the Meizu Pro 5 lol.

Comment: I believe it IS a feature of bq E5 device, but there ain't any option  yet to activate it in Ubuntu Touch. See this video: https://youtu.be/L0FTpimZj24

Comment: Also there's this feature request: http://pad.lv/1573193

Comment: Indeed @pomsky, I was wrong - just to note: I flashed the stock Android on the Aquaris E5 Ubuntu edition, and indeed, it has a menu entry in Settings/Display called "Double tap control" (other phones may have it as "(double) Tap to wake up") - when this is active, the phone can be waken with a double tap on screen. Cheers!

Comment: That sure would be nice to have.

Comment: I have added a comment on the feature request as this would really be something nice to have.